# Error in Publishing a page in Tridion?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I am using Tridion 2011. The problem is- whenever i try to publish a page,its publishing gets failed. When I checked Publish Transaction, it shows that publishing is getting failed in Deployment phase.

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue and how to correct it?

Thanks.

Comment: Check your CD logs - the error details should be found there if they're not shown in Publish Transaction.

Comment: As Jeremy said...check your logs for errors. Set the logging to DEBUG in your logback.xml, clean the logs, restart your deployer and check what stacktraces you get while publishing.

Comment: Are you using the HTTP Deployer?  Can you hit the webpage?

Comment: @robrtc : yes i m able to hit the httpupload.aspx and i m getting "SDL Tridion ASPX HTTP Upload" written on the page.

Comment: Please review the deployer config and cd_storage config.  Verify the destination folder in the storage config exists to validate all files are in place.  Specifically, make sure the Java files are correct in the Lib folder.  Also, please have a look at Nuno's article on manually configuring a Tridion 2011 .NET Content Delivery system.

Answer (score 5):

There can be literally a million reasons why deployment fails:

1. Database is not connected
2. Database is mis-configured
3. Ran out of disk space
4. Password is wrong
5. User running deployer doesn't have permissions to write to file system

and many many more.

The easiest way to figure out what's wrong is to look at the logs that your deployer provides, you're likely to find the error in cd_core_.log or cd_deployer_.log. Check logback.xml for the location of these files.

If you can get the error from these files and post it here we may have better suggestions for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try giving permissions to user -NetworkService on folder where the package is deployed.
Also could you please specify the detailed error?